# Liquibase not running in Spring Boot Kotlin project

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, liquibase

I created a project an Spring Boot project, version 2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, with Gradle and Kotlin. I want to use liquibase also, but I can't make it work.

With the same setup, but using Java I can make liquibase work.

This is my resources folder:

[image]

And these are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or error messages? How does your project directory layout look like? Are you using Maven or Gradle? You have to provide more information that we can help you

Comment: I don't get any error message, I think liquibase is not even trying to execute, and I don't have a datasource. I'm using Gradle

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have a datasource" and please provide the directory structure

Comment: Hi SImon, thanks for your message. I edited the comment and attached the resources folder and the dependencies in build.gradle.kts

Answer (score -1):

Add the liquidbase dependency

```
implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.2")
```

Comment: and a property `liquibase.enabled` has value `true`?

Comment: that's for Spring boot 1. If instead of Kotlin I use Java, it works

Comment: what version of spring boot, kotlin and java do you use exactly?